# Can I remove parameter from URL generated by video playlist in Elementor

Tags: elementor

Elementor Pro has a new widget, video playlist. It appends a parameter to the URL, like so: http://aaronpenton.net/ampcreative/vip/about-vip/?playlist=f68425e&video=b8a9967

This is obviously terrible for SEO and UX. Is there a way to remove the ?playlist=f68425e&video=b8a9967 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My brother help me with the next script.
Put a "HTML Elementor Widget" with the following:

```
    <script>
function getURLParameter(name) {
  return decodeURI((RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]);
}

function hideURLParams() {
  //Parameters to hide (ie ?playlist=value, ?video=value, etc)
  var hide = ['playlist','video'];
  for(var h in hide) {
    if(getURLParameter(h)) {
      history.replaceState(null, document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML, window.location.pathname);
    }
  }
}

window.onload = hideURLParams;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```js
const url = 'http://aaronpenton.net/ampcreative/vip/about-vip/?playlist=f68425e&video=b8a9967'
url.replace(url.split('/')[6], '')
```

1. `split`, well.. splits the string into an array by the `/`
   character.
2. At index `6` the array contains the `?playlist=f68425e&video=b8a9967` substring which can than be removed (i.e. replaced by the empty string)  using `replace`.

A more general approach to removing the last part of the url might
be to use the array length instead of specifying the index:

```js
const url = 'http://aaronpenton.net/ampcreative/vip/about-vip/?playlist=f68425e&video=b8a9967'
const urlArr = url.split('/')
url.replace(urlArr[urlArr.length - 1], '')
```

---

**Update:**

Another way to do this is using the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

```js
const url = new URL('http://aaronpenton.net/ampcreative/vip/about-vip/?playlist=f68425e&video=b8a9967');
const result = url.origin + url.pathname
```

or in a function:

```js
const removeParameter = u => {
  const url = new URL(u);
  return url.origin + url.pathname
}
```

You might have to check the specification for further details (browser support etc)

Comment: This is brilliant as I’m learning JavaScript and to my shocking surprise your solution makes perfect sense. Thanks for the breakdown!

Comment: I added an example using the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL). This might be even better as it provides you with readily available and reusable properties and methods. Among major browsers, only Internet Explorer is not supporting the use of this api.

Comment: Please excuse my newbness, but this would ne to be put into a function and then you’d call the function, correct? And would this script need to go in the head of the document? I added it via the add JS feature in Elementor. It added it to the bottom of the page, but isn’t working.

Comment: I don't know anything about Elementor, but a function for this could be defined like the example I added in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233995/discussion-between-hektor-misplon-and-espskully).